# Is there any other Alternative for 'IN' and 'OR' operators in Objectify(The Cloud Datastore SDK does not currently support 'IN' filters). -java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

Entity 1

```
@Cache
@Entity
public class EmployeeDO {
  @Id
  @Index
  private Long employeeId;

  @Index
  @Load
  private Ref<CompanyDO> companyId;
}
```

Entity 2

```
@Cache
@Entity
public class CompanyDO {
  @Id
  @Index
  private Long companyId;

  @Index
  private String mailingAddress;
}
```

I want filter Entity 1 with list of companyIds.

I'm using **appengine-sdk version 1.9.68** and **Objectify version 6.0.6**. Any suggestions will be helpful **thank you**.

Answer (score 1):

The old appengine datastore SDK implemented IN filtering client-side, so... you can basically do the same. Issue a separate query for each id. It's not especially efficient, but it never was - and I think they used to limit you to 30 entries in the IN clause.